# Finding a primitive element for the Hilbert Class Field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-14})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

> I am trying to solve exercise 6.18 in the book of David Cox. I have tried to provide as much context as possible to make the situation as clear as possible for the reader.

[image]

> I have solved exercise 6.17 succesfully. I am having trouble solving 6.18 (a) and (b).

---

> I also tried to solve the rest of exercise 6.18. However, my argument is not always completely sound. Below I have given a detailed outline of my (partial) answer. Comments and feedback are always welcome.

[image]
[image]

> Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer. Feedback and corrections always welcome!**

(a) I was not able to solve this part of the exercise in a satisfactory way. However, one way to approach it would be to show that $Gal(L/K) = \mathbb{Z}_4$. Next, one could invoke the following theorem

[image]

to find that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is the dihedral group of order $8$. I would like to avoid this advanced approach. There must be a much simpler approach using only Galois theory. Can somebody help me?

(b) idem.

---

(c) A straightforward calculation shows that

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma^2(\sqrt{uu'}) &=&\sigma\left(\sigma(\sqrt{u} \sqrt{u'})\right) \\
&=&\sigma\left(\sigma(\sqrt{u}) \sigma (\sqrt{u'})\right) \\
&=& \sigma \left (\sqrt{u'} (- \sqrt{u})\right) \\
&=& \sigma (\sqrt{u'}) \sigma(- \sqrt{u})) \\
&=& -\sqrt{u} (- \sqrt{u'})  \\
&=& \sqrt{uu'}
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma \tau (\sqrt{uu'}) &=& \sigma \left( \tau (\sqrt{u} \sqrt{u'})\right) \\
&=& \sigma \left( \tau (\sqrt{u}) \tau( \sqrt{u'})\right) \\
&=& \sigma \left ( \sqrt{u} (- \sqrt{u'}) \right) \\
&=& \sigma( \sqrt{u}) (- \sigma(\sqrt{u'})) \\
&=& \sqrt{u'} (- (-\sqrt{u})) \\
& =& \sqrt{u u'}
\end{eqnarray}$$

This shows that $\sqrt{uu'}$ is fixed by both $\sigma^2$ and $\sigma \tau$. Hence, by part (b) this means that $\sqrt{uu'}$ lies in the fixed field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. Say that $\sqrt{uu'}=a+b\sqrt{-7}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, then

$$\begin{eqnarray}
- a - b \sqrt{-7} &=& -(a+b\sqrt{-7}) \\
&=& - \sqrt{uu'}  \\
&=& \tau(\sqrt{uu'}) \\
&=& \tau (a+b\sqrt{-7}) \\
&=& \tau(a) + \tau(b\sqrt{-7}) \\
&=& a - b\sqrt{-7} \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
such that $a=0$. Hence $\sqrt{uu'}=m \sqrt{-7}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. To see why $m$ is indeed an integer, and not a rational number, square both sides.

---

(d) Observe that
$$N(u)=N(a+b\sqrt{2})=a^2 - 2b = (a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=uu' = -7m^2$$

Furthermore, since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a UFD and $u=a+b\sqrt{2}$, we can factor $u$ uniquely, say

$$u=p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$$

Taking norms we see that at least one of those primes needs to have norm $-7$. The exercise suggests that this element will be $\pi=2 \sqrt{2}-1$.

$\color{red}{\text{But how can I conclude that this is the only possibility?}}$ Probably there are many more elements with norm $-7$, right? Anyway, let $\alpha$ be everything besides $\pi$ in the above factorization, then $N(\alpha)=m^2$, and $\alpha$ is the desired element.

---

(e) $\color{red}{\text{Why can one assume that there are no square factors of $u$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?}}$ This is not the question at stake, but I would like to know why.

Anyway, since $N(\alpha)=N(m)$, both elements must differ by a unit $\epsilon$, i.e. $\alpha = \epsilon \cdot m$. Hence $u = \pi \alpha = \epsilon \pi n$. The change of $m$ to $n$ in the exercise only seems to be a notational convenience.

By a famous theorem of Dedekind, one can now determine the prime elements. This question was also raised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674814/prime-elements-in-mathbbz-sqrt2). However, Alex Youcis claims his answer was incomplete. He basically outlines two options. But in the context of my exercise, it seems that I only need to have option one, namely

$$p \equiv 3, 5 \mod{8}$$

$\color{red}{\text{I don't see why the other option must be excluded}}$. Anyway, combining this with the above, and the fact that $u$ has no squares (why?), we get that

$$u=\epsilon \pi (p_2 \ldots p_r)$$

with $p_2,\ldots p_r$ integer primes. From $p \equiv 3,5 \mod{8}$ it is clear that none of the above integer primes can be equal to $2$ or $7$.

---

(f) Now,

$$ u \mathcal{O}_L = \pi \mathcal{O}_L \cdot n \mathcal{O}_L$$

with $u = \sqrt{u}\sqrt{u}$ a square. This is clear, one just has to recall that one is working again in the bigger ring and no longer in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. As a consequence, each prime which divides $n$ ramifies in $\mathcal{O}_L$. On the other hand, there is a famous theorem which says that

> $$p \textrm{ ramifies in } L \Leftrightarrow p \mid d_k$$

Since $d_k=56$, we have that $p=2$ and $p=7$ would ramify in $L$. But this would mean that $p=2,7$ divides $n$. But this is a contradiction because of part (e). I need to refine this argument somewhat more, but from this I must conclude that $n=\pm 1$.

---

(g) From the previous part we know that $n = \pm 1$. Assume $n=1$ and write
$$u = \epsilon \pi$$
If $n=-1$ just change the unit to $\epsilon'$. We know that all units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ are of the form $\pm (\sqrt{2} - 1)^m$. Now, by our original assumption (again: why?), $u$ had no square factors, hence we should not consider anything of the form $\pm (\sqrt{2}-1)^{even}$. So, we only consider $\epsilon = \pm (\sqrt{2}-1)^{odd}$. But, since

$$N(\epsilon) = N(\pm (\sqrt{2}-1)^{odd})=-1$$

and 
$$-7 = N(u)=N(\epsilon) N(\pi) = -7 N(\epsilon),$$

this can never happen. So the only possiblity left is that $\epsilon= \pm 1$. But since $\pi = 2 \sqrt{2} - 1 > 0$ and $u>0$ by assumption, we can conclude that $\epsilon=1$.

---

**Conclusion:** Putting everything together we have that $u = \pi = 2 \sqrt{2} - 1$ and this gives us the primitive element for the Hilbert Class Field

$$L=K\left(\sqrt{2 \sqrt{2} - 1}\right)$$