# Finding Prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

I want to prove that prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ has one of the following forms:

(1) $\sqrt{2}$

(2) $p = 1,7 \quad mod \;\;8$

(3) integer primes $p=3,5 \;mod \; 8 $.

I was able to prove (1) and (3), but couldn't figure out (2).

Comment: Suppose that $11$, let us say, we're reducible. Then we would render $11=(a+b\sqrt2)*(a-b\sqrt2)=a^2-2b^2$. If $b$ is even then $a^2-2b^2\in\{0,1,4\}\bmod8$, if $b$ is odd we get $\{2,6,7\}\bmod8$. There is a problem getting it to equal $11$, no?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, why did you choose $11$? and why you assume that $11$ can be written as product of a number and its conjugate?

Comment: @Adam_math This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/917932/724407) answers your question. Notice that (2) in your post is not a valid claim.